# How to call method requiring parameters type int using stack of a different type

Tags: java, stack, overloading

I have a stack of type UserEntry which takes in either 3 or 4 ints.

Using method overloading I've written two methods.

```
public void addUserEntry(int row, int col, int rowTwo, int colTwo) {
    do something
}
    
public void addUserEntry(int row, int col, int num) {
    do something    
}
```

I'm trying to call the methods using a for each loop on the stack

```
for(UserEntry ue : stack){    
        addUserEntry(ue);
}
```

I'm getting the error no suitable method found (UserEntry). I was thinking as the loop iterated through the stack it could output 3 or 4 ints and call the correct method but it seems I need a new method which accepts type UserEntry as a parameter.

Is there a way to make the method accept the numbers from the stack as type int and not as type UserEntry?

Comment: We don't know what `UserEntry` is so we can't help you in converting it into 3 or 4 ints.

Comment: You are passing in an object of type `UserEntry` but all the functions expect `3` or `4` parameters.

Comment: I would eliminate the three-`int` and four-`int` versions of `addUserEntry`, make a single `addUserEntry` that takes a `UserEntry`, and then provide three-`int` and four-`int` constructors for `UserEntry`.  Then, your loop _just works_, and problem solved.  But, to answer your question, No, there is **no way** to make an object (`UserEntry` or otherwise) magically "unpack" itself into the right number  of arguments for a method call.